# Can I access a struct/class member from a template?

Tags: c++, templates, member

What I want to do is create a function that accepts any class or struct (via templates), but also have the function assume that there's always a specific member in the passed-in class or struct.

In probably-not-correct-code, it would look something like this:

```
template <class inputType>
int doSomething(inputType voxel)
{
    return voxel.density;
}
```

I want it to assume that `density` member will always be there and that it will always be an `int` (or whatever). Can I do that? And if so, what happens if `density` doesn't exist? Will it simply throw a compiler error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's perfectly legal, templates in C++ are not comparable to a different approach (think Java) that type checks the generic method or classes by keeping the type variable.

A C++ template is compiled with every possible type you are using it, so every single instantiation for every specific type is compiled and type checked. If you try to access a field which is not contained in the type you are using `doSomething` with, then you will get a compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do this, templates are going to be instantiated at compile time and if the type does not have that member it will not compile and you will receive an error. Templates functions are basically contracts and as long as the type you are using conforms to the contract, it will work.

In this case I would also suggest you experiment with it, sites like [C++ Shell](http://cpp.sh/) and [onlinegdb.com](https://www.onlinegdb.com/) make experimenting with C/C++ pretty easy and painless anywhere you are and they support the latest versions. You will learn a lot more by trying out things like this.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that. I know I should have tried this out in code _before_ asking, but that would mean either a lot of time modifying my current project or creating a new project just to test. Neither options were very appealing. (Just tried LiveWorkSpace and the website appears to be down.)

Comment: @Clonkex I use LiveWorkSpace pretty often but I noticed it was down now so I added the second link which has many other options as well. I normally do not suggest for someone to just experiment but you seemed to have enough information to successfully work things out and sometimes knowing the barrier to experiment is lower than you think can help.

Comment: Absolutely; if I'd thought of using online C++ compilers before posting the question I would have. I considered creating a new project just to test it, but then I decided that it would probably be better to make sure that it was actually allowed in C++, even if it compiled successfully (it might compile but then cause hidden problems later on). Thanks for the link :)

Comment: LiveWorkSpace is not a thing any more, fyi